# Voting on "Who's good for the Jews?"

Tags: halacha, politics-government, voting

In a civil election, does Judaism teach that one should vote for candidates who will be "good for the Jews" (i.e. they support laws that are more favorable to Jews as a whole than the laws that the other candidate supports)?

What if the voter supports the other candidate's positions on every other issue much more?

Comment: Very similar, but, I think, not quite a dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/voting-for-a-person-that-will-not-uphold-torah-values

Comment: I have to ask you to clarify if this is a dupe of @IsaacMoses's linked question. Because I find it ambiguous as to what you mean by "good for the Jews". Do you mean "supports school vouchers in a neighborhood facing a tuition crisis"? Do you mean "supports tax cuts for a particular class which includes many Jews"? Do you mean "upholds Torah values" (a dupe of the other question)? (And which Jews? Where?)

Comment: @SethJ I don't mean specifically "upholds Torah values. I am mostly referring to your second example and also perhaps an example where he supports (or opposes) legislation that is directly about Jews.

Comment: Well, I'd advise opposition to a candidate whose stated position is specifically about Jews, one way or the other, because one road down which that leads is most certainly not good for the Jews.

Comment: "A voter on a question of communal interest must "state his opinion for the sake of Heaven and for the benefit of the city",[6] and while I have long been uncertain as to whether this really means that an individual voter must set aside any personal interest he has in the affair and reach his best disinterested judgment of the general community's interest, it certainly means that tampering with an election renders it illegitimate and voids the result.[7]"