# Voting as a Jew or as a member of that country.

Tags: halacha-theory, voting

Assuming one is voting. Is one required to vote in line with which ever candidate is closer to Halacha (however that is determined) or is one required or allowed to vote with what he thinks is better for his country of residence. For example Halacha forbids gay marriage, if without Halacha (I was a non-Jew) I would believe that Liberty demands that people have the right to marry whoever they want. Can I vote for the candidate that supports gay marriage? (Just an example that came to mind not meant to be specific)

Comment: this might be a better dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29042/759

Comment: Of course, no candidate will perfectly agree with your interpretation of every Torah value.

Comment: @mevaqesh http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8477/5151