# PTIJ: Who should I vote for? (21st Knesset Edition)

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It is an obligation to participate in creating the Knesset, as the halacha says (SA OC 150:1):

> כופים ... זה את זה לבנות ... הכנסת
>
> [People] should force one another to build ... the Knesset.

Today the Knesset is "built" on our votes.

So we see that we must vote, the question now is who to vote for?

Please provide sources that "specifically mention"* a candidate or party running in the current Knesset elections as someone either worth voting for or who should not be voted for.**

* Sources can be Biblical, Talmudic, or Halachic, but the mention **must** be Purim Torah -- based on a pun or misunderstanding of the quote. I specifically do **not** want any real modern-day rabbis saying who to vote for in this election. The candidate/party can be identified either by name or by a defining characteristic.

** It shouldn't just be any "mention" of the candidate's name, but rather specifically something related to voting or a position of power, etc.

Obviously this is not the final stand on who to vote for, as always, consult your rabbi.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

#### Please leave your personal politics out of this.

Note that we are **not** telling you who to vote for in this question. For some real Torah-based opinions on what to take into account when voting, see the following questions:

- [Voting for Jews in elections](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29044/voting-for-jews-in-elections)
- [Voting on "Who's good for the Jews?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29042/voting-on-whos-good-for-the-jews)
- [Voting for a person that will not uphold Torah values](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/voting-for-a-person-that-will-not-uphold-torah-values)

(This question is a copy of my [question from a few years ago](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69350/5151) about the US elections.)

Comment: BTW I see Bibi mentioned all over the Gemara - בבי this, בבי that

Comment: Welcome back, feels like ages I haven't seen you around !!

Comment: @mbloch Thanks! You're right, i haven't been around much, but i do still stalk SE and read stuff.

Comment: Welcome back Scimonster!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems like Kulanu is a good, qualified party for leadership, as we proclaim in the Passover Haggada:

> כולנו חכמים, כולנו נבונים, כולנו יודעים את התורה
>
> Kulanu are wise, Kulanu are insightful, Kulanu know the Torah

Those seem like good qualities for leadership of the Jewish State.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn’t vote for any of these guys, they all speak modern Hebrew, and transgress the Shulchan Aruch [52:12:](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.53.12)

> אין ממנין מי שקור' לאלפי"ן עייני"ן ולעייני"ן אלפי"ן:
>   One should not appoint a person [to be leader] who reads "aleph"s like "ayin"s and "ayin"s like "aleph"s.

Maharsha (Megillah 24a) cites this terrible phenomenon as only occurring with people from חיפה and בית שאן in Israel. Therefore, according to the Shulchan Aruch, we shall only appoint those who do not hail from these two locations.

Comment: The Shas candidates don't speak properly?

Comment: You shall probably vote for them, then! @heshy

Comment: Only ashkenazim make that mistake

Comment: @Loani And Haifans and Beit Shaanites - Megillah 24b

Comment: @Loani, as do many Israeli Sephardim

Answer (score 5):

Do not vote for anyone from [Yesh Atid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesh_Atid). As the Talmud (Menachot 29) tells, they stand directly in the way of the giving of the Torah.

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב בשעה שעלה משה למרום מצאו להקב"ה שיושב וקושר כתרים לאותיות אמר לפניו רבש"ע מי מעכב על ידך אמר לו אדם אחד יש שעתיד
>
> Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: When Moses ascended on High, he found the Holy One, Blessed be He, sitting and tying crowns on the letters of the Torah. Moses said before God: Master of the Universe, who is preventing You from giving the Torah? God said to him: Any man from Yesh Atid.

Answer (score 4):

We should vote for Kadima, as it says in Bamidbar 34:3

> והיה לכם גבול נגב, מקצה ים-המלח קדמה
>
> And the Southern border all the way to the Dead Sea shall be yours, Kadima

Comment: I don’t think Kadima exists anymore

Comment: "party running in the current Knesset elections" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do, do NOT vote for Likud, as Rashi writes on Iyov 15:24:

> כאותו המלך שהוא עתיד ליקוד באש של גיהנם
>
> Like that ruler whom He will, [from] Likud, [place] in the fires of Gehinnom.

Obviously the reasoning is as we say in Selichos of Aseres Yimei Teshuvah:

> חַיַּת בְּנוֹ לִיקוֹד כִּקְדוֹחַ אֵשׁ הֲמָסִים:
>
> A beast is his son, Likud, like raining down fire [on] Chamas.

Surely we should try to make peace with them, rather than rain fire on them.

Comment: I understand the second source to be comparing Likud to Hamas’s fires (missiles or incendiary balloons)

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do, don't vote for [Gesher](https://gesherparty.co.il/): they might not get enough votes to get over the threshold and your votes might be lost -- as R Nachman mi Breslev [teaches us](https://youtu.be/XjCyVSciLXM?t=52)

> כָּל הָעוֹלָם כֻּלוֹ] **גֶשֶׁר צַר מְּאֹד**]
>   
> (Gesher will be very narrow)

Comment: But doesn't it mean Gesher will narrowly pass? Get into the Knesset by a very narrow margin?

Comment: Or they will narrowly miss.... too risky - make your voice count !

Answer (score 1):

Vote for Likud, as per the [Midrash of R’ Akiva](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_Midrashim_of_Rabbi_Akiba,_Aleph_Bet_of_Rabbi_Akiba_(Version_1).39):

> וליקוד לך
>
> And Likud will be for you

Likewise we say in Selichos of Aseres Yimei Teshuvah:

> חַיַּת בְּנוֹ לִיקוֹד כִּקְדוֹחַ אֵשׁ הֲמָסִים:
>
> A beast is his son, Likud, like raining down fire [on] Chamas.

Chamas is an existential threat to Israel. We need a leader like this.

Answer (score 0):

מקור מים חיים על בעל שם טוב
ויקרא, ט׳:ב
‘שס טוב’- sha”s is good