# PTIJ: Who should I vote for? (23rd Knesset Edition)

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

One year ago [Scimonster](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100807/ptij-who-should-i-vote-for-21st-knesset-edition) asked who we should vote for for the 21st Knesset. Well, luckily for us we get another opportunity to answer that question. Since the question has not changed that much I will quote the rules used last time:

> Please provide sources that "specifically mention"* a candidate or party running in the current Knesset elections as someone either worth voting for or who should not be voted for.**
>
> * Sources can be Biblical, Talmudic, or Halachic, but the mention must be Purim Torah -- based on a pun or misunderstanding of the quote. I specifically do not want any real modern-day rabbis saying who to vote for in this election. The candidate/party can be identified either by name or by a defining characteristic.
>
> ** It shouldn't just be any "mention" of the candidate's name, but rather specifically something related to voting or a position of power, etc.
>
> Obviously this is not the final stand on who to vote for, as always, consult your rabbi.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Please leave your personal politics out of this.

Comment: "consult your rabbi" - what if my rabbi tells me to consult Mi Yodeya?

Comment: @Harel13 https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3485/13438

Comment: Well, the only letter that doesn't appear in the 10 commandments (Yitro version) is 'ט'.   I suppose that could be a symbol of something.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise against voting for Shas as several organizations, including [Dirshu](https://hamodia.com/2020/02/09/yidden-join-dirshu-siyum-hashas/), [Hadran](https://hadran.org.il/womens-siyum-hashas/) & [Agudas Yisrael](https://www.thesiyum.org/) have announced that Shas is finished.  They even had large festivities called a Siyum HaShas, a party to celebrate that Shas is finished.

On the other hand, many said they would return to Shas. "Hadran alecha Shas..."

Comment: Good thing it's alecha Shas and not alayich Shas, otherwise one would've thought that they were feminists, chalilah...

Comment: @Harel13 it should probably be עליכון

Comment: You're bringing a proof from [Agudas Yisrael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agudat_Yisrael)? Clearly that's political propaganda meant to make their opponents look bad.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite what you are looking for, but it does say:

> תעל שועתם אל האלהים מן העבדה

Which obviously means that T"aal's (the Arab party) salvation will come from votes to the Labor party.

Comment: Nice! I tried to think of a connection to the Arab party but only got as far as ערבי נחל...

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Pirate Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Party_of_Israel) is going to make it big, which is why one should vote for them, as it says in [Yirmiyahu 6:26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.6?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> כִּ֣י פִתְאֹ֔ם יָבֹ֥א הַשֹּׁדֵ֖ד עָלֵֽינוּ

Translation: Suddenly, the Pirate was upon us.

[Zechariah 11:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zechariah.11.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) also prophesied of the future crowning of the Pirate [Party] and the wisdom he/they have:

> ק֚וֹל שַׁאֲגַ֣ת כְּפִירִ֔ים כִּ֥י שוֹדד גְּא֥וֹן הַיַּרְדֵּֽן

Translation: The sound of the roar of the lions [[which symbolizes monarchy]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6INp3k-vFc), for the pirate is the genius of the Jordan [river].

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that Labor/Gesher will be a good tactical voting choice, as Rav Nachman said:

גשר צר מאד‏

This indicates that there will be very few seats  available for the party, so everyone will have to squeeze in. Of course, you should still vote for them if you believe in their message, as Rav Nachman also said:

והעיקר לא לפחד כלל

So vote for Labor/Gesher only if you truly support them.

Comment: _Gesher tzar m'od_ means Gesher is very like a czar, so should rule; _v'haikar lo l'fached_ means the farmer should not fear.

Answer (score 0):

According to Rashi, you should not vote for Likud. He writes on [Iyov 15:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Job.15.24.2):

> עתיד ליקוד באש של גיהנם
>
> In the future, Likud will be in the fire of Gehennom.

But according to the [paytan in the Nusach Sefard version of Selichos of 20 Sivan](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Fast_Days%2C_Selichot_for_20_Sivan.49), you absolutely should vote for Likud:

> ליקוד כקדח אש חמסים
>
> Likud is like the drilling of fire into Hamas.

And certainly you want Hamas to be destroyed!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bamidbar Rabbah 2:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.2.12), only vote for Blue and White if you live in a coastal city.

> רביה לבן וכחול אשר על שפת הים
>
> Increase White and Blue on the edge of the sea.

But you should only vote for the [Yesh Atid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesh_Atid) branch if you believe we are approaching the end of days, as the Gemara says ([Menachos 29b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.29b.3)):

> יש שעתיד להיות בסוף
>
> Yesh Atid will be in the end

And do not vote for Telem, as the Gemara elsewhere ([Sanhedrin 113a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.113a.11)) writes:

> אוקים ליה עבודת כוכבים על כל תלם
>
> He established for him an idol on all of Telem.

Voting for Telem is thus prohibited by idolatry.