# PTIJ: What are the political implications of Purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Mordechai is introduced as אִ֥ישׁ יְמִינִֽי׃ -- *ish yemini*, that is, "a man of the right".  [Esther 2:5]

Since he is a good and wise man, one to emulate, is this description a subtle way to teach us that good Jews should always vote Republican?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Methinks this should be an answer to [PTIJ: Who should I vote for? (23rd Knesset Edition)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111594/ptij-who-should-i-vote-for-23rd-knesset-edition) rather than its own question.